# Shorthand way to take an array of Ruby models and turn it into a hash with the id as the key?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of models that I would like to turn into a hash so I can reference them by id. I know I can iterate over the items and put them in a hash, but I know there must be a quick, shorthand way of doing this same thing:

```
my_models_hash = {}
@my_models.each do |model|
  my_models_hash[model.id] = model
end
```

How can I do this same thing in one, short line?

Comment: If you're using Rails/ActiveSupport, there's `@my_models.index_by(&:id)`

Comment: @Stefan Please turn this into an answer. It's a great option and I'd like to up-vote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're after `each_with_object`.

```
my_models_hash = @my_models.each_with_object({}) { |m,h| h[m.id] = m }
```

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
@my_models.map { |m| [m.id, m] }.to_h
```

Prior to v2.0, this would have to be written:

```
Hash[@my_models.map { |m| [m.id, m] }]
```

Comment: Only in modern rubies, though.

Comment: @Sergio, my rule of thumb is that I don't need to mention the version when Ruby gained a feature if was 1.9 or earlier.  I thought `to_h` was added in 1.9, but no, it was 2.0.  Thanks.

Comment: Unless a version is specifically mentioned, you should assume the latest version by default.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails (or more specifically [ActiveSupport](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html)), there's [`Enumerable#index_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-index_by):

```
@my_models.index_by(&:id)
#=> { 1 => #<Model id: 1, ...>, 2 => #<Model id: 2, ...>, ...}
```